# Gaussian distribution and probability of occurence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gaussian, standard-deviation

consider a column Eye_width:

```
Index    Eye_width
15643    58.5
11873    54.6
4651     62.4
5767     66.3
9787     66.3
15236    54.6
8380     54.6
12254    58.5
13549    70.2
12413    58.5
16194    54.6
12655    62.4
12574    62.4
8922     58.5
9037     62.4
5283     66.3
12616    58.5
10       70.2
11481    58.5
17659    50.7
14220    54.6
11857    62.4
3945     42.9
13495    58.5
15430    54.6
1606     66.3
18423    50.7
20       62.4
12117    66.3
14208    50.7
2180     58.5
17114    62.4
2796     58.5
12716    54.6
5514     66.3
12232    66.3
811      62.4
6631     50.7
15123    58.5
9164     54.6
16615    62.4
13441    58.5
12679    62.4
1781     54.6
3994     58.5
16825    54.6
6120     66.3
3596     66.3
1934     62.4
16273    50.7
```

Here I like to know few statistical info, I prefer to get few information out of these like:

1. Gaussian distribution of the column
   2.Its mean 
   3.Standard deviation. 
   4.Importantly the probability of occurrence of each value in that column. Example probability of 58.5 is 0.2, 54.6 is 0.1 and so on.. The total probabilities of all values add upto 1.
   5.Consider When the gaussian distribution curve is extended along x axis to 3 Standard deviations on X axis on either side extrapolated. Now the total area consists of 6 stds . This area for example would be covered with 1000 samples. Among this 1000 smaples I need info like 58.5 has occurred 155 times , 50.7 has occurred 200 times and so on for all values. Also the information like how many samples is consumed for the first 50.7 to occur. Similarly for other values in that column. It is again the concept of probability and extrapolation, but I need to know how can it be done programmatically

Comment: Not very clear what you want. Are you asking how to calculate mean and standard deviation of a pandas series? You can find that in the docs...Regarding 3, your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how many samples are 3 std's away from the mean? Your question regarding uniqueness of the values and counts again isn't very clear...

Comment: I edited , maybe it is quite clear now